# Qt error Invalid use of incomplete type 'class UI::FrameLess'

Tags: c++, qt, class, user-interface

I keep getting this error and I don't know why. It just says incomplete type of my class FrameLess. I don't think im missing including any files. I also want to specify that I have a mainwindow besides this widget and im trying to implement a UI form for my class FrameLess. Any help would be great. Thanks!

frameless.h

```
#ifndef FRAMELESS_H
#define FRAMELESS_H

#pragma once
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QRubberBand>
#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QtCore/QEvent>
#include <QtCore/QRect>
#include <QtCore/QPoint>
#include <QtCore/Qt>
#include <QtGui/QHoverEvent>
#include <QtGui/QMouseEvent>
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class FrameLess;
}


class FrameLess : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum Edge {
        None = 0x0,
        Left = 0x1,
        Top = 0x2,
        Right = 0x4,
        Bottom = 0x8,
        TopLeft = 0x10,
        TopRight = 0x20,
        BottomLeft = 0x40,
        BottomRight = 0x80,
    };
    Q_ENUM(Edge);
    Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(Edges, Edge);

    FrameLess(QWidget *target);

    void setBorderWidth(int w) {
        _borderWidth = w;
    }
    int borderWidth() const {
        return _borderWidth;
    }

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e) override;
    void mouseHover(QHoverEvent*);
    void mouseLeave(QEvent*);
    void mousePress(QMouseEvent*);
    void mouseRealese(QMouseEvent*);
    void mouseMove(QMouseEvent*);
    void updateCursorShape(const QPoint &);
    void calculateCursorPosition(const QPoint &, const QRect &, Edges &);

private:
    QWidget *_target = nullptr;
    QRubberBand *_rubberband = nullptr;
    bool _cursorchanged;
    bool _leftButtonPressed;
    Edges _mousePress = Edge::None;
    Edges _mouseMove = Edge::None;
    int _borderWidth;
     Ui::FrameLess *ui;
    QPoint _dragPos;
    bool _dragStart = false;



};

Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(FrameLess::Edges);
#endif
```

frameless.cpp:

```
#include "frameless.h"
#include "ui_frameless.h"

FrameLess::FrameLess(QWidget *target) :_target(target),_cursorchanged(false),_leftButtonPressed(false),_borderWidth(5),_dragPos(QPoint()), ui(new Ui::FrameLess)
{
   // ui->setup(this);
    _target->setMouseTracking(true);
    _target->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    _target->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
    _target->installEventFilter(this);
    _rubberband = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle);
}

bool FrameLess::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent*e) {
    if (e->type() == QEvent::MouseMove ||
        e->type() == QEvent::HoverMove ||
        e->type() == QEvent::Leave ||
        e->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress ||
        e->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) {

        switch (e->type()) {
        case QEvent::MouseMove:
            mouseMove(static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(e));
            return true;
            break;
        case QEvent::HoverMove:
            mouseHover(static_cast<QHoverEvent*>(e));
            return true;
            break;
        case QEvent::Leave:
            mouseLeave(e);
            return true;
            break;
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
            mousePress(static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(e));
            return true;
            break;
        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
            mouseRealese(static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(e));
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        return _target->eventFilter(o, e);
    }
}

void FrameLess::mouseHover(QHoverEvent *e) {
    updateCursorShape(_target->mapToGlobal(e->pos()));
}

void FrameLess::mouseLeave(QEvent *e) {
    if (!_leftButtonPressed) {
        _target->unsetCursor();
    }
}

void FrameLess::mousePress(QMouseEvent *e) {
    if (e->button() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        _leftButtonPressed = true;
        calculateCursorPosition(e->globalPos(), _target->frameGeometry(), _mousePress);
        if (!_mousePress.testFlag(Edge::None)) {
            _rubberband->setGeometry(_target->frameGeometry());
        }
        if (_target->rect().marginsRemoved(QMargins(borderWidth(), borderWidth(), borderWidth(), borderWidth())).contains(e->pos())) {
            _dragStart = true;
            _dragPos = e->pos();
        }
    }
}

void FrameLess::mouseRealese(QMouseEvent *e) {
    if (e->button() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        _leftButtonPressed = false;
        _dragStart = false;
    }
}

void FrameLess::mouseMove(QMouseEvent *e) {
    if (_leftButtonPressed) {
        if (_dragStart) {
            _target->move(_target->frameGeometry().topLeft() + (e->pos() - _dragPos));
        }

        if (!_mousePress.testFlag(Edge::None)) {
            int left = _rubberband->frameGeometry().left();
            int top = _rubberband->frameGeometry().top();
            int right = _rubberband->frameGeometry().right();
            int bottom = _rubberband->frameGeometry().bottom();
            switch (_mousePress) {
            case Edge::Top:
                top = e->globalPos().y();
                break;
            case Edge::Bottom:
                bottom = e->globalPos().y();
                break;
            case Edge::Left:
                left = e->globalPos().x();
                break;
            case Edge::Right:
                right = e->globalPos().x();
                break;
            case Edge::TopLeft:
                top = e->globalPos().y();
                left = e->globalPos().x();
                break;
            case Edge::TopRight:
                right = e->globalPos().x();
                top = e->globalPos().y();
                break;
            case Edge::BottomLeft:
                bottom = e->globalPos().y();
                left = e->globalPos().x();
                break;
            case Edge::BottomRight:
                bottom = e->globalPos().y();
                right = e->globalPos().x();
                break;
            }
            QRect newRect(QPoint(left, top), QPoint(right, bottom));
            if (newRect.width() < _target->minimumWidth()) {
                left = _target->frameGeometry().x();
            }
            else if (newRect.height() < _target->minimumHeight()) {
                top = _target->frameGeometry().y();
            }
            _target->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(left, top), QPoint(right, bottom)));
            _rubberband->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(left, top), QPoint(right, bottom)));
        }
    }
    else {
        updateCursorShape(e->globalPos());
    }
}

void FrameLess::updateCursorShape(const QPoint &pos) {
    if (_target->isFullScreen() || _target->isMaximized()) {
        if (_cursorchanged) {
            _target->unsetCursor();
        }
        return;
    }
    if (!_leftButtonPressed) {
        calculateCursorPosition(pos, _target->frameGeometry(), _mouseMove);
        _cursorchanged = true;
        if (_mouseMove.testFlag(Edge::Top) || _mouseMove.testFlag(Edge::Bottom)) {
            _target->setCursor(Qt::SizeVerCursor);
        }
        else if (_mouseMove.testFlag(Edge::Left) || _mouseMove.testFlag(Edge::Right)) {
            _target->setCursor(Qt::SizeHorCursor);
        }
        else if (_mouseMove.testFlag(Edge::TopLeft) || _mouseMove.testFlag(Edge::BottomRight)) {
            _target->setCursor(Qt::SizeFDiagCursor);
        }
        else if (_mouseMove.testFlag(Edge::TopRight) || _mouseMove.testFlag(Edge::BottomLeft)) {
            _target->setCursor(Qt::SizeBDiagCursor);
        }
        else if (_cursorchanged) {
            _target->unsetCursor();
            _cursorchanged = false;
        }
    }
}

void FrameLess::calculateCursorPosition(const QPoint &pos, const QRect &framerect, Edges &_edge) {
    bool onLeft = pos.x() >= framerect.x() - _borderWidth && pos.x() <= framerect.x() + _borderWidth &&
        pos.y() <= framerect.y() + framerect.height() - _borderWidth && pos.y() >= framerect.y() + _borderWidth;

    bool onRight = pos.x() >= framerect.x() + framerect.width() - _borderWidth && pos.x() <= framerect.x() + framerect.width() &&
        pos.y() >= framerect.y() + _borderWidth && pos.y() <= framerect.y() + framerect.height() - _borderWidth;

    bool onBottom = pos.x() >= framerect.x() + _borderWidth && pos.x() <= framerect.x() + framerect.width() - _borderWidth  &&
        pos.y() >= framerect.y() + framerect.height() - _borderWidth && pos.y() <= framerect.y() + framerect.height();

    bool onTop = pos.x() >= framerect.x() + _borderWidth && pos.x() <= framerect.x() + framerect.width() - _borderWidth &&
        pos.y() >= framerect.y() && pos.y() <= framerect.y() + _borderWidth;

    bool  onBottomLeft = pos.x() <= framerect.x() + _borderWidth && pos.x() >= framerect.x() &&
        pos.y() <= framerect.y() + framerect.height() && pos.y() >= framerect.y() + framerect.height() - _borderWidth;

    bool onBottomRight = pos.x() >= framerect.x() + framerect.width() - _borderWidth && pos.x() <= framerect.x() + framerect.width() &&
        pos.y() >= framerect.y() + framerect.height() - _borderWidth && pos.y() <= framerect.y() + framerect.height();

    bool onTopRight = pos.x() >= framerect.x() + framerect.width() - _borderWidth && pos.x() <= framerect.x() + framerect.width() &&
        pos.y() >= framerect.y() && pos.y() <= framerect.y() + _borderWidth;

    bool onTopLeft = pos.x() >= framerect.x() && pos.x() <= framerect.x() + _borderWidth &&
        pos.y() >= framerect.y() && pos.y() <= framerect.y() + _borderWidth;

    if (onLeft) {
        _edge = Left;
    }
    else if (onRight) {
        _edge = Right;
    }
    else if (onBottom) {
        _edge = Bottom;
    }
    else if (onTop) {
        _edge = Top;
    }
    else if (onBottomLeft) {
        _edge = BottomLeft;
    }
    else if (onBottomRight) {
        _edge = BottomRight;
    }
    else if (onTopRight) {
        _edge = TopRight;
    }
    else if (onTopLeft) {
        _edge = TopLeft;
    }
    else {
        _edge = None;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the complete error message, do not summarize it.

Comment: The error is: "Invalid use of incomplete type 'class UI::FrameLess' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this by recreating a simple project and copying in your code, making it a "Qt Designer Form Class" (which I think you also did), and recreated the same error as you did.

But, looking at the code sample, this is not really intended to be a *QDialog* but rather a *QObject*, i.e. a class deriving from the main Qt base class (`QObject`). So it should not be used that way.

I looked at the code and saw these lines in the constructor:

```
FrameLess::FrameLess(QWidget *target) :_target(target),_cursorchanged(false),_leftButtonPressed(false),_borderWidth(5),_dragPos(QPoint()), ui(new Ui::FrameLess)
{
   // ui->setup(this);
    _target->setMouseTracking(true);
    _target->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    _target->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
    _target->installEventFilter(this);
    _rubberband = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle);
}
```

As can be seen, this class takes in a target widget and *modifies* this widget, making it frameless (by e.g. setting the according window flags, attributes etc.). So the proper use case would be something like this, in the class where you want it to be used:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    new FrameLess(this);
}
```

The constructor call (`new Frameless(this)`) will modify the object that you pass to it in this way.

---

So, to get your example working, either *recreate* it in Qt Creator as a plain *QObject*-derived class, or to just do a quick test, remove from this part of the constructor:

```
FrameLess::FrameLess(QWidget *target) :_target(target),_cursorchanged(false),_leftButtonPressed(false),_borderWidth(5),_dragPos(QPoint()), ui(new Ui::FrameLess)
```

...the `, ui(new Ui::FrameLess)` part there at the end. I.e. don't assign anything to the `ui` class member.

In the `.h` file, remove this part:

```
private:
    QWidget *_target = nullptr;
    QRubberBand *_rubberband = nullptr;
    bool _cursorchanged;
    bool _leftButtonPressed;
    Edges _mousePress = Edge::None;
    Edges _mouseMove = Edge::None;
    int _borderWidth;
     Ui::FrameLess *ui; // <- remove this
    QPoint _dragPos;
    bool _dragStart = false;
```

By doing these changes, I could get your example working, but it's probably best to recreate it/delete the `frameless.ui` dialog from your project - it isn't used anyway, so it's best to just remove it.

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Thank you ! But I need the frameless.ui so that i can edit the user interface. I want a resizeable transparent frameless window, with a .ui file so i can add buttons and stuff to it.

Comment: Yes. Please re-read my answer. You create the window with the `.ui` file and all that, then from the constructor in your window class, call `new FrameLess(this)` - the `FrameLess` class will then _adjust_ your window class instance so that it's frameless. You could perhaps also merge the content from the `FrameLess` class into your UI class (like you tried), but it might require more changes so I suggest going with this approach at first.